# Creating functional spatial index of ST_Geometry Feature Class in ArcSDE for Oracle?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, spatial-index

Copied an SDE feature class (with blob(sdebinary(?) geom) into the same SDE GDB (Oracle 11g/SDE 9.3.1) but with the ST_geometry configuration keyword.  I can see that the feature class was created, all the fields come across fine, I can query it with st_geom functions etc., BUT in ArcMap, ArcCatalog, the features don't draw. (*note that when *selected* I can see the outline of the shape just fine)  When I remove the spatial index the features draw, add the spatial index back, *poof* no draw.  It would seem that ArcGIS cannot create a functional spatial index of my ST_Geometry features.

Comment: These look related. For your disappointment, I haven't found a solution to this one so far.

Comment: I figured it out but as a noob I can't answer my own question (for a few more hours).  The answer is outlined by ESRI [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/creating-95168347.htm).

Comment: if this solves my problem too...oh...oh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I should have read the documentation here:
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/creating-95168347.htm

The solution was an Oracle 'create index' query a la:

```
create index sa_idx on st_parks(shape)
indextype is sde.st_spatial_index 
parameters('st_grids=1000 st_srid=5');
```

Ran into a 'maximum number of grids per feature' exceeded error, and then realized that the grid size is a function of the measurement unit of the spatial reference.  So by originally passing in st_grids=1 (like the documentation) it was creating a 1 foot spatial index grid...and yeeeah...that was a little excessive.

Hopefully Esri will fix their create spatial index tool to accommodate Oracle.